# How to slice tensors in loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor, loss-function

In my custom loss function, I tried to use .numpy() to convert tensors to numpy arrays but it didn't work. After some searching it seems not possible to convert tensors to numpy arrays in a loss function. So I decided to use backend methods. As you can see in the following code, I used K.argmax() and return a index tensor of the max value. Then I would like to slice the y_true, y_pred tensors.

```
def my_mse_loss(y_true, y_pred):

    y_true_index = K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1)
    y_true_startcounter = y_true_index-3
    y_true_stopcounter = y_true_index+3

    y_pred_index = K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
    y_pred_startcounter = y_pred_index-3
    y_pred_stopcounter = y_pred_index+3

    y_true_pkrange = y_true[:,y_true_index:y_true_index+6]
    y_pred_pkrange = y_pred[:,y_pred_index:y_pred_index+6]

    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred_pkrange-y_true_pkrange), axis=-1)
```

The error I got when I fitted the model:
ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 0 and 2
From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for '{{node my_mse_loss/strided_slice/stack_2}} = Pack[N=2, T=DT_INT64, axis=0](my_mse_loss/strided_slice/stack_2/values_0, my_mse_loss/ArgMax)' with input shapes: [], [?,384].

Comment: Your error might be unrelated to slicing. Make sure that your `y_true` tensor has the same shape as `y_pred`.

Comment: I tried  y_true = K.squeeze(y_true, axis=-1), and I got TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got <tf.Tensor 'my_mse_loss/ArgMax:0' shape=(None,) dtype=int64>

Comment: what are your `y_true` and `y_pred` shapes?